# Do CDN such as cloudfront have any limitation to maximum volume of cache that can be stored in a distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am trying to understand the pricing of CDN in AWS, GCP and Azure.

One thing I am not able to figure out is, if there is any limit to total amount of cache which can be stored in a single distribution, and is there any added cost as the total volume of cache keeps on increasing.

To give my prospective:-

Usecase 1) Using CDN for delivering 1_000_000 files of size 100KB in a location daily, with retention time of **1day**.

Total Volume of data present in cache (1year later): `1_00_000 * 100KB * 1 = 100GB`

Total Bandwidth consumed (1year later): `1_000_000 * 100KB * 365 = 3650GB`

Usercase 2) Using CDN for delivering 100 files of size 100MB in a location daily, with retention time of **1years**.

Total Volume of data present in cache (1year later): `100 * 100MB * 365 = 3650GB`

Total Bandwidth consumed (1year later): `100 * 100MB * 365 = 3650GB`

(**Note:** Let's assume in the use case above all the files counted are always unique.)

So speaking of cloudfront, it will mainly charging me for the bandwidth, which is same for both the use cases. However in Usecase 2 the resources spent for storing the cache is a lot higher.

**My question is am I missing something in the pricing, or CDN providers don't care about storage costs?**

Comment: Why do you multiply by `365`? The files stored for 1 year or for 1 day take same amount of space.

Comment: In usecase2 , 1 year old cache will be retained, where as in usecase 1, the cache is cleared daily.

Comment: Which is why I mentioned 1 year later

Comment: So why would it take `100 * 100MB * 365 = 3650GB`? Shoudn't it be`100 * 100MB  = 365GB`? The amount of space does not increase the longer your store it.

Comment: OK, Let's consider the data I mentioned is always unique. the cache is never used. All my users fetch unique data. so unique data which stays for 1 years keeps adding up.

Comment: I see. So you have new 100 files each day.

Comment: So size of cache is virtually unlimited and you pay for it with transfer fees.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236219/discussion-between-rishav-cnx-and-marcin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding CloudFront. Cache size is virtually unlimited and you pay for it with **transfer fees**. The fact that you set "retention time of 1years" does not mean your files will stay in cache for that long. If AWS deems your files as **in-frequently** used, it will purge them well before they get 1 year old. From [docs](http://h%20retention%20time%20of%201years):

> If a file in an edge location isn't frequently requested, CloudFront might evict the file—remove the file **before its expiration** date—to make room for files that have been requested more recently.